# Why this oracle query returning empty result set?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two database tables with some demo data like shown below

```
Create table demo(uuid int, addressname varchar(50));

insert into demo values(1, 'intersportprofi');
insert into demo values(2, 'intersportprofi');
insert into demo values(3, 'intersportprofi');
insert into demo values(4, 'intersportmarket');
insert into demo values(5, 'intersportmarket');
insert into demo values(6, 'intersportmarket');

create table demo_av(uuid int, testid int, name varchar(50), value varchar(50));

insert into demo_av values(1, 1, 'sport','football basketball cricket');
insert into demo_av values(2, 1, 'brand','reebok  addidas nike');
insert into demo_av values(3, 2, 'sport','football basketball ');
insert into demo_av values(4, 2, 'brand','reebok  addidas ');
```

I wrote the following query to get the results from those tables, but oracle returning empty result set.

```
SELECT  d.addressname  FROM demo d, demo_av dv
WHERE  d.uuid = dv.testid  AND d.addressname='intersportprofi' 
AND REGEXP_LIKE( dv.value, 'reebok') AND REGEXP_LIKE( dv.value, 'cricket')
```

Why? where i am doing wrong ? Any help will be greatly appriciated

Comment: Because no row has both `reebok` and `cricket` ?

Comment: You shouldn't be storing multiple values in a single column. Normalize your data model and the query gets a *lot* easier.

Comment: I dont have the possibility to normalize the database, i have to cope with existing one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments, I think you want a query that will search over multiple rows with same `testid`. This can be done with joins or like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.addressname  
FROM demo AS d
WHERE d.addressname = 'intersportprofi' 
  AND EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM demo_av AS dv
        WHERE d.uuid = dv.testid 
          AND dv.value LIKE '%reebok%'
      )
  AND EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM demo_av AS dv
        WHERE d.uuid = dv.testid 
          AND dv.value LIKE '%cricket%'
      ) ;
```

Comment: Sorry but what just happened? I've presented the questioner by the result and he already mentioned that it's working. Also my post was the correct answer. What is this?

Comment: @Mohammad Goudarzi this is the solution that i am looking for. your query is working but it is giving unwanted result for me

Comment: Sorry for things happend but, i would like take this opportunity to say big thank to u

Comment: Happy to hear that. :) It's strange, something like when you buy a house, oneday you come in and see someone else suddenly is living there! ;D I could have change the code if you had helped me a little. Cheers bro.

Answer (score 5):

Change this:

```
AND REGEXP_LIKE( dv.value, 'reebok') AND REGEXP_LIKE( dv.value, 'cricket')
```

To this:

```
AND (REGEXP_LIKE( dv.value, 'reebok') OR REGEXP_LIKE( dv.value, 'cricket'))
```

Because:

You have no record in the `"demo_av"` table that matches with `"reebok"` **AND** `"cricket"`. The operator you need is `"OR"` and the parantheses are ***necessary*** because of existing of the first condition.

**UPDATE**

Here is the capture screen of the results:

[image]

Cheers

Comment: thank you very much for your reply , but there exists 'cricket' in the value column for the same id. How can i get results with and condition ? That is mandatory for me

Comment: The code I mentioned will give you exactly what you're looking for. Tell me if you had any problem with making it works. Cheers bro...

Comment: in the above query if 'reebok' matches to 10 rows it returns 10 roes and if 'cricket' matches to another 8 rows totally this returns 18 rows. But i want the 'addressname' which contains both. How can i do that ?

Comment: No, in **OR** if the first condition returns **true** the second condition will never be checked cause if it would be checked, it was not the act of **OR** anymore! I think you should analyse the output result instead of analysing the logic before the execution. ;)

Comment: A **OR** B => A = 1, B = 0 => TRUE (there is no need to check the value of B)

A **AND** B => A = 1, B = 0 => FALSE (because of checking the B value is 0)

Comment: @user964147 Hey body, don't you wanna accept my post as an answer man? ;D

Comment: Ok i executed this query it returns me three rows which i not correct SELECT  d.addressname  FROM demo d, demo_av dv
WHERE  d.uuid = dv.testid  AND d.addressname='intersportprofi' 
AND (REGEXP_LIKE( dv.value, 'reebok') OR REGEXP_LIKE( dv.value, 'cricket'))  may be you can try

Comment: Sir I've executed the query and it seems perfectly correct. The result should be three rows. Change the **d.addressname** to '*' to see all the columns and you will see why it's correct.

Comment: I agrree with u, my bad and thanx for lot of patiency

Comment: Cheers bro, I've just uploaded the capture screen of the results. Happy to hear it worked for you.. ;)